# NDSolve::ndsz error: singularity or stiff system suspected | Coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica. Trying to solve the below coupled-ODEs (eqnA, eqnB, eqnC). However, getting error NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.8849324488967629`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
Referring to other related posts, tried solutions like changing the method to StiffnessSwitching, and other options like WorkingPrecision, etc, but nothing is working.

```
g  = 5/3;
eqnA = (y2[x]-x)x y1'[x] + (x y2'[x]+ y2[x])y1[x] == 0;
eqnB= -3/2  y1[x]y2[x]  + (y2[x] - x)y1[x]y2'[x] + y3'[x] == 0;
eqnC = -3 y1[x] y3[x] + (y2[x] - x)(y1[x]y3'[x] - g y3[x] y1'[x] )== 0;
sol=NDSolve[{eqnA,eqnB, eqnC,y1[1]== (g+1)/(g-1),y2[1]== 2/(g+1), y3[1] == 2/(g+1)},{y1,y2,y3},{x,0,1}];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x],y2[x],y3[x]}/.sol[[1]]],{x,0,1}]
```

Expecting a plot somewhat like this.

[image]

Comment: Solving for the derivatives shows that they become singular when `2 x (3 x^2 y1[x] - 6 x y1[x] y2[x] + 3 y1[x] y2[x]^2 - 5 y3[x])` vanishes.  Check whether this is the cause of the integration stopping.

Comment: I just checked, and that is exactly what is happening.  This is a math issue, not a Mathematica issue.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Ok! But how we can solve this problem?

Comment: @twilight Is there exact solution you shown?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The plot is not the exact solution. I am expecting a plot of the functions similar to that.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I do not think that we can integrate through the singularity.

Comment: @bbgodfrey is there any possible workaround?

Comment: These are Taylor-von-Neumann-Sedov equations (transformed into ODEs by self-similarity method) for cylindrical symmetry. reference- R.P. Drake's  High-Energy-Density Physics: cha-4 Shocks and rarefactions

Comment: I am not optimistic that there is a work-around.  If I recall correctly, compressible fluid equations exhibit singularities when shocks form, and these can be eliminated only when additional physics is included.  Have others been able to integrate these equations?

Comment: if that were the case, the same problem should arise for the spherical symmetry case. isn't it? Regarding cylindrical case, I came across one paper with the plot, though the boundary conditions were different than what I have taken in this problem. While solving for spherical case too, I encountered the same error but for x << 0.1; but the overall plot seemed acceptable.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you for responding

Comment: the plot that i attached in this problem is for the spherical case

Comment: The singularity occurs where `3 y1[x] (x - y2[x])^2 - 5 y3[x]` equals zero.  The numerical value depends on boundary conditions.  The singular part of the solution can be approximated by `c1(1 + ProductLog[-Exp[-1 + c2(x-x0)]])`, where x0 is the point at which the singularity occurs.

Comment: The coefficients of the ODEs weren't right. When I solved them again, I got the right coefficients and the desired plot using them. Your comments have been more than helpful. Thank you very much.